# php save data from multiselect, multi row

Tags: php

I have a multselect input and I need to save selection to database. 1 selected student_id = I row in database. How can I do it?

view:

```
<select select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="student_id" multiple="multiple" id="student_id" style="width: 100%;">
    <option value="">Select student</option>
</select>
```

controller:

```
$student_id = $this->input->post(['student_id']);
array( "student_id"=>$student_id,
```

Thanks for help

Comment: `$student_id` should be an array of values, so you need to split it up into separate values and insert each one into a separate row (e.g. by using a loop, perhaps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
<select name="student_id[]" size="10" multiple="multiple">

$str = '';
foreach ($_POST['student_id'] as $student) {
    $str .= $student;
}

$imploded_ids = implode(',', $str);
$student_id = $this->input->post(['student_id']);
 array( "student_id"=>$imploded_ids,
```

**EDIT :**

```
$iddss = $_POST['student_id'] ; //Take the array of ids.

$values = array() ;

foreach($iddss as $str){
  $values[] = $str;
}

$LastValue = implode(",", $values);
$student_id = $this->input->post(['student_id']);
       array("student_id"=>$LastValue,
```

Use result of idds

Comment: I works. But not good. It saved student_id as one number: 515253 to one row. But student_id were 51,52,53 and I need to save it to 3 rows.

Comment: @Jayjay See updated answer, both solutions should work now. let me know

Comment: I tried first solution and i doesnt work: Severity: Warning

Message: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Comment: second solution sais: Severity: Parsing Error

Message: syntax error, unexpected '$imploded_ids' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: @Jayjay try second one

Comment: YES! it works. It saves student_id with commas to one row. You make my day. Just a last question: Is it possible to generate every single row for each student_id?

Comment: @Jayjay I dont think there is a way to do that with in arrays! Glad I helped. Can you please accept and upvote answer. Thanks